# How to use getActionBar()/getSupportActionBar() when using material theme and AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design

My application returns null on getActionBar() with android 4.4 and below, from research so I can see this is because my app is using a material theme for Android 5 and AppCompat for older versions.

However I cant see to fix the return null issue, or get getSupportActionBar() working, below is my code, what needs changing so that I can use getActionBar/getSUpportActionBar on older android but still use material theme on 5.

My Activity:

```
public class MapsActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        ...
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);

    if (toolbar != null)
    {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); // or other
    }

        ...
    }
...
}
```

v21/style.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- your app's theme inherits from the Material theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- Main theme colors -->
        <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/primary</item>

        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

gradle dependency

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

my XML layout (after changes made by answer)

```
RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111">s


    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

toolbar_default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"/>
```

ToolBarStyle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources><style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
</style></resources>
```

Error below answer gives:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.zpwebsites.whatsintown/com.zpwebsites.whatsintown.MapsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.zpwebsites.whatsintown.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:80)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.zpwebsites.whatsintown.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:80)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:747)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3730)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:491)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:487)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:195)
            at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.<init>(Toolbar.java:191)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.zpwebsites.whatsintown.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:80)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: you must use `ActionBarActivity` with the support library

Answer (score 6):

Add to your activity xml layout code below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    />
```

It will add actionbar where you want.

In your activity `onCreate`

Write this:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (toolbar != null)
        {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); // or other
        }
```

And use only getSupportActionBar / setSupportActionBar

Your activity should extend `ActionBarActivity`

In your app theme add:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

It should work perfectly.

And one more thing - you can use AppCompat theme on Lollipop too. On Lollipop AppCompat theme is extending Material theme so... they are doing it for you ;-)

Check how Google guys achieve that in Google IO app: https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android/src/main/res

Comment: after changing my xml I get and error when running the app (xml and error above)

Comment: You have placed toolbar in wrong place.  Check this tutorial http://antonioleiva.com/material-design-everywhere/

Comment: have updated to show current code but still not working

Comment: @ZacPowell you have wrong xml layout for met. DrawerLayout should be root of your view if you want to achieve 'standard' actvity with navigation drawer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html), you will be able to use getSupportActionBar() as long as you include the following as your dependencies in your Gradle file.

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7'

To use this correctly, include your activity's name as the context in your res/menu folder's toolbar_default.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MapsActivity">
     ... 
</menu>
```

Note that the context's value is the name of the activity you want to use this toolbar in.

Then, in your activity's file:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    ...

    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    // insert a floating value for the elevation 
    actionBar.setElevation(0f);
    // do your other action bar's customisation here
}

...


// Make sure you implement this method, otherwise your menu won't show up 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Here I tell Android to inflate your menu
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_default, menu);
    return true;
}
```

For more information, please refer to the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)